# TensorFlow Traceback (most recent call last): tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.PermissionDeniedError: /tmpp error

Tags: python, python-3.x, permissions, tensorflow, traceback

I just recently downloaded TensorFlow, and it worked fine with a simple sketch. But now with a bigger program it's giving me an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sergei/Documents/neural Network, tensorflow.py", line 4, in <module>
    mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("/tmpp/data/", one_hot=True)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/datasets/mnist.py", line 227, in read_data_sets
    SOURCE_URL + TRAIN_IMAGES)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/datasets/base.py", line 205, in maybe_download
    gfile.MakeDirs(work_directory)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py", line 314, in recursive_create_dir
    pywrap_tensorflow.RecursivelyCreateDir(compat.as_bytes(dirname), status)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 66, in __exit__
    next(self.gen)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 466, in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status
    pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.PermissionDeniedError: /tmpp
```

I am a little frustrated any help or suggestions would be great, here's the code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data

mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("/tmpp/data/", one_hot=True)

n_nodes_hl1 = 500
n_nodes_hl2 = 500
n_nodes_hl3 = 500

n_classes = 10
batch_size = 100

x = tf.placeholder('float',[None, 784])
y = tf.placeholder('float')

def neural_network_model(data):

    hidden_1_layer = {'weights':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([784, n_nodes_hl1])),
                      'biases':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_noded_hl1]))}


    hidden_2_layer = {'weights':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl1, n_nodes_hl2])),
                      'biases':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_noded_hl2]))}


    hidden_3_layer = {'weights':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl2, n_nodes_hl3])),
                      'biases':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_noded_hl3]))}


    output_layer = {'weights':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl3, n_classes])),
                      'biases':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes]))}



    l1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(data, hidden_1_layer['weights']), hidden_1_layer['biases'])
    l1 = tf.nn.relu(l1)


    l2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(data, hidden_2_layer['weights']),  hidden_2_layer['biases'])
    l2 = tf.nn.relu(l2)


    l3 = tf.add(tf.matmul(data, hidden_3_layer['weights']), hidden_3_layer['biases'])
    l3 = tf.nn.relu(l3)

    output = tf.matmul(l3, output_layer['weight']) + output_layer['biases']

    return output


def train_neural_network(x):
    prediction = neural_network_model(x)
    cost = tf.reduce_mean( tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logit(prediction,y) )
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(cost)

    hm_epochs = 10

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

        for epoch in hm_epochs:
            epoch_loss = 0
            for _ in range(int(mnist.train.num_examples/batch_size)):

                epoch_x, epoch_y = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)

                _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict = {x: epoch_x, y: epoch_y})

                epoch_loss += c
            print('Epoch', epoch, 'completed out of', hm_epochs, 'loss:',epoch_loss)


        correct = tf.equal(tf.argmax(prediction,1), tf.argmax(y,1))
        accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct, 'float'))
        print('Accuracy:',accuracy.eval({x:mnist.text.images, y:mnist.test.labels}))



train_neural_network(x)
```

Here is another error I got when I fixed the tmp problem and a few other small problems!!

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/common_shapes.py", line 671, in _call_cpp_shape_fn_impl
    input_tensors_as_shapes, status)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 66, in __exit__
    next(self.gen)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 466, in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status
    pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 784 and 500 for 'MatMul_1' (op: 'MatMul') with input shapes: [?,784], [500,500].

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sergei/Documents/neural Network, tensorflow.py", line 79, in <module>
    train_neural_network(x)
  File "/Users/sergei/Documents/neural Network, tensorflow.py", line 52, in train_neural_network
    prediction = neural_network_model(x)
  File "/Users/sergei/Documents/neural Network, tensorflow.py", line 39, in neural_network_model
    l2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(data, hidden_2_layer['weights']),  hidden_2_layer['biases'])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py", line 1801, in matmul
    a, b, transpose_a=transpose_a, transpose_b=transpose_b, name=name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_math_ops.py", line 1263, in _mat_mul
    transpose_b=transpose_b, name=name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 768, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2338, in create_op
    set_shapes_for_outputs(ret)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1719, in set_shapes_for_outputs
    shapes = shape_func(op)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1669, in call_with_requiring
    return call_cpp_shape_fn(op, require_shape_fn=True)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/common_shapes.py", line 610, in call_cpp_shape_fn
    debug_python_shape_fn, require_shape_fn)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/common_shapes.py", line 676, in _call_cpp_shape_fn_impl
    raise ValueError(err.message)
ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 784 and 500 for 'MatMul_1' (op: 'MatMul') with input shapes: [?,784], [500,500].
```

Comment: it should be 'tmp' not 'tmpp'

Comment: cool thanks that fixed a good bit of it!

Comment: what do i do i got another error!

Answer (score 0):

First, let's look at the error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sergei/Documents/neural Network, tensorflow.py", line 79, in <module>
    train_neural_network(x)
  File "/Users/sergei/Documents/neural Network, tensorflow.py", line 52, in train_neural_network
    prediction = neural_network_model(x)
  File "/Users/sergei/Documents/neural Network, tensorflow.py", line 39, in neural_network_model
    l2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(data, hidden_2_layer['weights']),  hidden_2_layer['biases'])
```

Aha, l2 is wrong.
Let's see what's wrong with l2

See

```
l1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(data, hidden_1_layer['weights']), hidden_1_layer['biases'])
l1 = tf.nn.relu(l1)

# `data` should be l1 
l2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(data, hidden_2_layer['weights']),  hidden_2_layer['biases'])
l2 = tf.nn.relu(l2)

# same error is found here
l3 = tf.add(tf.matmul(data, hidden_3_layer['weights']), hidden_3_layer['biases'])
l3 = tf.nn.relu(l3)

output = tf.matmul(l3, output_layer['weight']) + output_layer['biases']
```

to

```
l1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(data, hidden_1_layer['weights']), hidden_1_layer['biases'])
l1 = tf.nn.relu(l1)

# data --> l1 
l2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(l1, hidden_2_layer['weights']),  hidden_2_layer['biases'])
l2 = tf.nn.relu(l2)

# data --> l2
l3 = tf.add(tf.matmul(l2, hidden_3_layer['weights']), hidden_3_layer['biases'])
l3 = tf.nn.relu(l3)

output = tf.matmul(l3, output_layer['weight']) + output_layer['biases']
```